# Incorrect Total displayed in a Power BI Visual

Tags: database, powerbi, dax

I need your help and would appreciate it.

First of all I show you the data model: (not the whole model, just the part we are interested in):
[image]

The problem is that the total is not displayed correctly. (If we sum up all the rows, we will see that it exceeds the total displayed at the table bottom).

[image]

I'm using the measure:  `Loans = SUM(CirculationFact[Count_Checkout])`.

Can someone explain me **why** does a simple SUM not work. Can it be caused by the presence of the bridge table?

Here I attached the pbix file: https://files.fm/f/emwb7m5fy.

I'll appreciate your answers :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The bottleneck of your model is a bridge table with relations to both directions. I would advice you to change your model into a star-shape or snowflake-shape, because such worm-shape models are ineffective and may lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: It's definitely the bi-directional filters that get you in trouble. Don't!

Answer (score 0):

hope you doing well.

Here you have an relationship issue, you can easily solve it just creating a master table of all yours products.

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the suggestions presented in the comment section to avoid bi-directional relationships are bad, since the data model is this way for a reason, and is a perfectly fine data model.

The issue you are facing is related to what is called **`semi-additive measures`** that materialize when you traverse across what is essentially a `many-many` relationship over the bridge table.

What you have calculated is not **wrong** by any means, but what is wrong is your impression of what this should be! Let me explain in a bit more detail using this (slightly) simpler data model that describes a couple of books that may be checked out, and each book can have multiple listed categories. I have highlighted the `many-many` relationship that is required for this to work as intended:

[image]

The data in each table is kept simple. We have three books and two categories, where only one of these books are actually related to both categories.

[image]

There are a **total** of 7 checkouts across all books, calculated with a simple measure:

```
# Checkouts = COUNTROWS ( Fact_Checkouts )
```

Now, what happens when we want to look at checkouts per `Category[Category]`? This is, as far as I can understand, what you are trying to do. We are left with what looks good but when you sum the rows it does not match up to the total:

[image]

Immediately this is perceived as being wrong, but it is actually just right. We need to go back to our data model to see what we are actually asking. We have one culprit here, that causes the semi-additive nature of this data model: `All is Fair in Love and War` has **two** categories, and any checkouts of this book will be counted both when the evaluation context is `Dim_Categories[Category] = Love` and when the evaluation context is `Dim_Categories[Category] = War`.

If we add the `Dim_Books[Title]` column to our table we can see that this book turns up twice:

[image]

But the book is not checked out separately as a `War` book or a `Love` book. When the evaluation context calls to count all checked out books that are tagged to the `Love` category, it will propagate this filter to `Fact_Checkouts` and count `Romeo and Juliet` 4 times and `All is Fair in Love and War` 2 times - for a total of 6 checkouts for any book associated with this **at least** this category. This is in line with expected results.

When the evaluation context is dropped in the total row, there is no active filter on `Fact_Checkouts` and the resulting value is just the row count of the table.

When you introduce a filter from `Dim_Categories` to the `# Checkouts` measure, the count will be corresponding to "how many checkouts have been for books associated with this category" - whereas without a filter from `Dim_Categories` the measure will be "how many times has any book been checked out". The confusing part is that the measure intuitively represents different things in the rows and in the total of your table.